# Camera View adjusting

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, qr-code

**I'm not too experienced with Swift or Xcode so any help would be appreciated!**

I have made a separate .swift file for my QR/Camera Controller. I found [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-create-a-qrcode-reader-in-swift-1b633d5ac95e) tutorial online on how to make a QR Code Reader and I typed in the Code provided and everything is fine except the Camera View isn't appearing properly on the Screen (using iPhone 8). **How can I adjust the Video View?**

**Code:**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CameraController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblOutput: UILabel!

    var imageOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation?
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var capturePhotoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a
        // device object and provide the video as the media type parameter
        guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) else {
            fatalError("No video device found")
        }
        // handler chiamato quando viene cambiato orientamento
        self.imageOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait

        do {
            // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous deivce object
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

            // Initialize the captureSession object
            captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

            // Set the input device on the capture session
            captureSession?.addInput(input)

            // Get an instance of ACCapturePhotoOutput class
            capturePhotoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            capturePhotoOutput?.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true

            // Set the output on the capture session
            captureSession?.addOutput(capturePhotoOutput!)
            captureSession?.sessionPreset = .high

            // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the input device
            let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

            // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
            captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]

            //Initialise the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
            previewView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

            //start video capture
            captureSession?.startRunning()

        } catch {
            //If any error occurs, simply print it out
            print(error)
            return
        }

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        self.captureSession?.startRunning()
    }

    // Find a camera with the specified AVCaptureDevicePosition, returning nil if one is not found
    func cameraWithPosition(position: AVCaptureDevice.Position) -> AVCaptureDevice? {
        let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)
        for device in discoverySession.devices {
            if device.position == position {
                return device
            }
        }

        return nil
    }

    func metadataOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureMetadataOutput,
                        didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject],
                        from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        // Check if the metadataObjects array is contains at least one object.
        if metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            return
        }

        //self.captureSession?.stopRunning()

        // Get the metadata object.
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr {
            if let outputString = metadataObj.stringValue {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(outputString)
                    self.lblOutput.text = outputString
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Image of current view:
[image]

The highlighted white box is the UIView

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is you use `frame` of `view` but add `videoPreviewLayer` to the `previewView` which is smaller (like you showed in storyboard).

Replace the line with `viewPreviewLayer` frame configuration.

```
        //Initialise the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer
        videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
        videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
        previewView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
```

this line

```
        videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
```

to

```
        videoPreviewLayer?.frame = previewView.layer.bounds
```

Comment: Also, do you know how to round the corners on the Camera View?

Comment: Yeh, it's simple.
Just setup it via layer property.
previewView.layer.masksToBounds = true
previewView.layer.cornerRadius = {your_value}

Comment: Thank you @LLIAJLbHOu, you are quite helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You should use NSLayoutConstraint from the storyboard.

Step #1

this is your current state
[image: this is your current state]

step #2

add top, leading, trailing and bottom constraint
[image: add top, leading, trailing and bottom constraint]

step #3

final result
[image: final result]

Answer (score 1):

I would expect one of the following happens:
 - You didn't setup your constraints properly
 - Your view resizes
 - You used incorrect view to set size of your layer

Setting up constraints is nearly impossible to explain by writing it. There are many ways of setting them up so I made a very short [video that explains one way (or two)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xIfLs4UwlM) about setting up constraints.

The second and third can be explained in this snippet:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        ...

    videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
    videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    previewView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
    updatePreviewLayerFrame()

        ...
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    updatePreviewLayerFrame()
}

private func updatePreviewLayerFrame() {
    videoPreviewLayer?.frame = previewView.bounds
}
```

Overriding `viewDidLayoutSubviews` should resize your layer as this method is called whenever the view controller "resizes". It is also called shortly after the `viewDidLoad`. Also note that a `previewView` is used to determine the frame: `videoPreviewLayer?.frame = previewView.bounds`.

Answer (score 1):

Layers do not automatically resize with their parent view. That means your `videoPreviewLayer` gets the frame from the original (not yet layouted) `previewView` and never changes it. To update the layer, you can override this method:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    // you need to keep a reference for that
    self.videoPreviewLayer.frame = self.previewView.bounds
}
```

Alternatively, and I think that's better, you can check out how the preview view is implemented in [Apple's AVCam example app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcam_building_a_camera_app). Resizing will be handled by Auto Layout when using their approach.